# Do 10k users get to read deleted comments?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, 10k-tools, deleted-comments

Do 10k (and moderator) users have the ability to read deleted comments (are comments deleted forever, or never really deleted like questions and answers)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, 10k+ users cannot read deleted comments, so a deleted comment is as good as gone.

The comments do, however, still exist in the database and ♦ moderators can read them and see who deleted them should an issue arise.

Comment: Do they end up in the data dump?

Comment: @Pollyanna: I imagine only non-deleted comments appear in the dump

Comment: At least some of the previous data dumps have included comments (including those with Bad Words).

Comment: (Indeed, @Pollyanna, in the past deleted comments erroneously showed in the data dump: [Data dump includes deleted comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36827/data-dump-includes-deleted-comments).)

Comment: According to Michael Mrozek in [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53480/are-comments-really-deleted/53483#53483): *This is out of date now; it's possible for mods to see deleted comments, but they have to ask for them specially (they're hidden normally)*

Comment: @Arjan: Confirmed (I'm a mod), and answer updated. You can remove your comments now. :-) I've also voted to close [the other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53480/are-comments-really-deleted/53483#53483) as a duplicate of this one. There's not much point in having both of them around.

Answer (score 7):

No, we (10k+ users) don't have that ability. They are as good as deleted forever (at least to non-moderators—those diamond folk can still see them).

Comment: According to Michael Mrozek in [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53480/are-comments-really-deleted/53483#53483), moderators can now see deleted comments if they want to.