# Data dump includes deleted comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-dump, deleted-comments

IIRC, the data dump is not supposed to include any content that has been deleted. Since I just stumbled over some deleted comments in the data dump, this suggests a bug in the exporter.

One such comment is number 877259, which I deleted and, after fixing some typos, replaced with comment 877279. As is visible [on the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065133/for-statement-in-python/1065149#1065149), only [comment 877279](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065133/for-statement-in-python/#comment-877279) is actually still around.

Examples of similar stories include

- comments 958129 and 958130 (deleted) and comment 958137 ([still there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140117/how-to-implement-a-box-or-gaussian-blur-on-iphone/#comment-958137))
- comments 1145915 and 1145920 (deleted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313401/bubble-sort-vs-merge-sort-closed))
- and more.

Now, if on the other hand this is on purpose, and the deleted comments are supposed to be in there, please turn this question into a feature request to let the data dump at least reflect the fact that a comment is deleted.

Comment: Hmmm, not that I care about people seeing it, but I still often use the old trick to post an edited comment and then delete the old one (instead of using that recent edit functionality). Now I see I'm actually messing up the database a bit.

Comment: @Arjan: Yep, that's the same thing that happened to me. But since Geoff says it will be removed, it should be gone from the latest data dump (I didn't check that yet, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleted comments will be removed from the next export.