# Why are comments not listed on the profile page too?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, profile-page

While playing around with the Stack Overflow [data-dump](http://www.rdbhost.com/rdbadmin/main.html?r0000000767), I was getting a feel for the schema and data by looking at my own posts and comments, and I happened coincidentally to notice my comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2003277#2003277) which turns out to have been popular. However, I had no idea until I stumbled upon it in the dump.

Shouldn't the profile page be a way to find everything that a given user has posted, be it a question, answer, or comment? I recognize that comments are definitely not the primary focus, and I wouldn't want to encourage commenting just for the sake of getting voted up (the comment in question was a drive-by comment that I never gave a second thought to until now). However, it would be nice to have a record of my past comments, or to be able to view comments of other users at a glance.

I think, in particular, the comments would be most valuable (or detrimental) to those using Stack Overflow et al as a resume since comments tend to illustrate a user's temperament and civility when dealing with others much more so that questions and answers which are often more carefully worded and edited.

Answer (score 7):

You pretty much answered the question yourself:

- Comments are lightweight; even as far as "they shouldn't contain information that you care about to persist".
- Comment voting even more so -- even though comments often get their votes for being witty, saying something funny, or including the words "freehand circles", the purpose of comment votes is to help a reader quickly identify those comments that are most relevant.
- The information is in the data dump, so if you want to revisit your comments, it's easy to do (of course I have done so myself, only to find [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36827/data-dump-includes-deleted-comments)) -- but that's what Jeff calls "information pornography".

Additionally,

- at least the most recent comments *are* shown on the profile page (in the activity tab).

Comment: +1 for "freehand circles."

Comment: @State: That comment obviously requires an upvote from me.

Comment: I'd at least like to know when I've posted a comment that has been received a lot of comment votes...

Comment: So maybe seeing comment voting has negatives, but is there anything wrong with just a list of all your comments?  Like I said, I think there's value in seeing if a prospective hire plays well with others.  And since that data is already out there, why make it hard to find? (Knowing your comments are easily read might actually encourage civility.)

Answer (score 2):

I am able to see all my comments in activity tab's comment section .
[image]