# Ability to see all your own comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are comments not listed on the profile page too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39584/why-are-comments-not-listed-on-the-profile-page-too)

I'd like to be able to see all my comments. Similar to how you can see all of your answers and questions. I understand it shows your comments on the activity tab but that only goes back so far.

My question is why shouldn't this be implemented. Some people may not want others to see all of there comments and if thats the case why not just make it so your can only see your own comments.

I'd like to be able to check the posts I have commented on every once in a while. Without having to favorite them.

Comment: I am able to all my comments in activity tab's comment section .