# The system sees a comment that doesn't exist

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

There is something strange with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522000/jpa-problems-mapping-relationships/2522023#2522023) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63594767/1481116). Basically, I left a comment on my answer. Some time after, I deleted it to "rewrite" it and the system seems to see a "ghost" comment now:

[image]

But if you click, look, there is no 1 more comment:

[image]

I see that the label also says "add" but it's the first time I see "folded" comments with 2 comments. Looks strange to me.

Comment: You broke it! Prepare to be disciplined for that :P

Comment: @balpha Yeah, this made me hesitating a long time before to post it.

Comment: I was surprised to learn that moderators or maybe even 10k's can see deleted comments as well. I took me some time to use the "edit" link when seeing a mistake within 5 minutes. For long I've just deleted and posted the corrected comment as well, not knowing I was messing up the system (or: messing up the view of those who get to see deleted things as well).

Comment: @Arjan: 10k users can't see deleted comments, and as far as I know, neither can moderators.

Comment: @Arjan Oh, I don't know if mods can see deleted comments (would makes sense) but 10k users can't, as shown on my screenshot :) Still, a delete/repost shouldn't mess the view. And something must have been changed between this morning and now (luckily I took a screenshot) because it seems fixed now.

Comment: @Pascal: Yes, it's fixed now. You have me as a witness that you weren't dreaming :) Maybe it was some sort of caching issue (denormalized comment count on posts or something like that), although this is the first time I've seen this happen.

Comment: @balpha and Pascal: you're right, I was wrong as my memory failed me: *Neither 10k+ users nor ♦ moderators can read deleted comments, so a deleted comment is as good as gone. The comments, do, however, still exist in the database and Jeff can see who deleted them should there be an issue.* according to December's http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/do-10k-users-get-to-read-deleted-comments (and a fixed bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36827/data-dump-includes-deleted-comments)

Comment: This happened to me as well just yet. I knew there were comments because I deleted some of mine and flagged others as NLN. Now that a mod cleaned them up there is this ghost collapser that is left. First I blamed caching, but it even persists in a private browser window.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The counts are denormalized so they can be slightly out of sync. This is rare, though.

The daily process will sync any that it finds that aren't right; this one is already correct now. (This process excludes deleted posts, so you may see incorrect comment counts that persist permanently on them.)