# Why comments on this question show one more comments but not really?

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The system sees a comment that doesn’t exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44249/the-system-sees-a-comment-that-doesnt-exist)

Why comments on this question show one more comments but when I click it nothing there?

[how can i use RegExp to grap data from this site ? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657172/how-can-i-use-regexp-to-grap-data-from-this-site)

or is it only me or my browser? I clear my cache btw, and tried on different browser, its same.

Comment: Oh, ho ho, ok. my bad!

Comment: As it's about comments of a closed question, while the auto-comment that warns about the duplicates seems to have been (auto-)deleted, it *might* also be related to [Not all comments shown, but no “show .. more comments”? (Or: auto-comments are not counted correctly?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44538/not-all-comments-shown-but-no-show-more-comments-or-auto-comments-are-no)

Comment: looks like, there is **no** one more comments now. seems temporary issue as jeff mentioned in another question.