# Are comments really deleted?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

Users with rep of 10k or more can see that certain user(s) deleted an answer but of course it is not deleted from the database and is available for users with higher reputation to see.

What about comments, are they also kept in the database for the moderators' analysis for various reasons or they are really deleted once we delete them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do 10k users get to read deleted comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/do-10k-users-get-to-read-deleted-comments)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, [they are not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36827/data-dump-includes-deleted-comments).

(Until mid 2011 moderators [could not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/do-10k-users-get-to-read-deleted-comments/32654#32654) see them either, but nowadays they can see deleted comments if they ask for them specially; they're hidden normally.)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know they retained them if they weren't a response.

Comment: @Tim, and one day some court [might tell Jeff to disclose them](http://superuser.com/questions/57167/where-do-deleted-gmail-messages-go/57193#57193)... ;-)

Comment: I knew it. Its that guy that keeps anonymously mailing his used socks to Jon Skeet. Sorry, I thought they caught him already.

Comment: This is out of date now; it's possible for mods to see deleted comments, but they have to ask for them specially (they're hidden normally)