# Stack Overflow data dump: Discrepancy of PostIDs in Posts.xml and Comments.xml

Tags: support, comments, data-dump

I am aggregating the URLs that have been shared on SO, and linking them back to the corresponding tags in the Question post.

Along the way, I noticed a subset of ~100 PostIds that have URLs in the comment section (Comments.xml), but when searching for the tag in the corresponding question (Posts.xml), the ID never comes up. See below for a complete list of such PostIDs.

Manual inspection shows that some of these posts are deleted, but some of them are still there, which suggests they should be present in both the Comments.xml and the Posts.xml.

Is this simply because the Post data was scraped before the comment data?

```
71368779
71368268
71368781
71368279
71368282
71368287
71368817
71368317
71368828
71368718
71368215
71368222
71368228
71368238
71368394
71367889
71368921
71368922
71367903
71368937
71368938
71368433
71368944
71367924
71368948
71368953
71367930
71368445
71368843
71368849
71368851
71368853
71368341
69812928
71368879
71368878
71368371
71368892
71368382
71368383
71368006
68475140
71368024
71368025
71368026
71368540
71368033
71369056
71368034
71368546
71368549
71368552
71368554
71368050
71368564
71368568
71368450
71368464
71367961
71350557
71367971
71367973
71368499
71368501
71367992
71368508
71368509
68443539
71368135
71368647
71368145
71368146
71079855
71368151
71368664
71368153
71369176
71368671
71368674
71368167
71368168
71368692
71368702
71368066
71368579
71368068
71368585
71368592
70942701
71368611
71368100
71369126
71368617
69193717
71368107
71368621
71368110
71368623
71368112
71369137
71368630
71368632
71369145
```

Comment: Interesting ... the ones starting with `7136` belong to a certain period early March; the other ones are part of a Collective.

Comment: Not sure what is going on. Here is a query to link those ids back to what we know today in SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1600763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a request that "[Data dump includes deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36827/282094)", and another
for "[Data dump should include deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33568/data-dump-should-include-deleted-posts)".

Normally when a post is deleted the comments go too, but that's not always the case.