# Should we be retaining a user's opinion in meta if they delete their account?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, per-site-meta, deleted-accounts

[As confirmed by *Shog9*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171694/dont-lock-votes-on-meta-sites/176675?noredirect=1#comment944059_176675), votes *may* be retained on the meta sites, if a user deletes their profile for that Stack Exchange site. This originates from [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted/268608#268608), where a user has brought up various issues involving user-deleted accounts and a request to retain votes.

It seemed odd that we should retain user votes in meta; especially when the original post seems to be specifically in context of a regular site. Should we be retaining a user's votes on a *secondary meta site* if that user deletes their profile?

Comment: somewhat related: [How did this curious undownvote pattern come about?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156507/165773) This old case has shown that if votes of an active user are invalidated this can lead to breaking voting anonymity (which seems to be very important for the system to work as intended)

Comment: Misread/misparsed. Edited it since my wider point still felt relevant

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, your entire post talks specifically about posts. If you can not understand how this is not relevant to the question, perhaps you should just flag the question as unclear?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we should.

And this question *and* self answer seem to ignore the "why" of why a user's posts are deleted, and well, what I feel is the *spirit* of meta.

One of the *slightly* unique things about the way many Stack Exchange sites are moderated is while we have some fixed rules about content, topics and so on, the community does have a *significant* amount of input over how we do things. I for one often reference back to meta when explaining to a new user why something was done a certain way.

As such, an answer isn't just the opinion of the person asking the question. It's the opinion of everyone who voted, and commented. Some of these answers might inspire alternate answers and are important.

Just because a user has decided he no longer wishes to be part of the site,  doesn't mean we don't care about what they've contributed to the community - especially if this is someone who has bothered to put in *meaningful meta posts* or has at least read them.

It might be different if it's a person who is *entirely* there to troll (or has devolved to trolling due to some frustration). Even then, it's better to have someone to judge the posts, and not the person.

By deleting any votes from someone who has chosen to delete his account, we lose context, maybe even change a decision that was made in the pas, and such. It would clearly be counterproductive.