# Flagging makes comment meaningless

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, deleted-comments

With relation to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133401/edit-makes-comment-meaningless-now-what) Question which is about editing the question makes a comment meaningless, today I saw another situation where when a comment was flagged and deleted comments following the flagged comment, became meaningless as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005846/solve-this-c-sharp-puzzle-it-has-to-be-a-simple-straight-answer) question.

In that scenario, after Jon Skeet's comment (2nd comment), other comments address the now deleted 3rd comment by the OP, which insulted one of the commentors. And since it is deleted, those comments following it, make no sense.

How can we avoid such a situation?

Comment: Actually, this is probably a better duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303105

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just as stated in the other meta question, flag as obsolete the comments that depend on the rude comment for context. Or if there are too many such comments and you don't want to flag them all, flag the question itself and inform us of the overall situation.

You don't have to do it now, though, as I've already taken care of it.

Comment: So, what will happen when the whole question is flagged? Will it improve the situation: meaningless comments

Comment: Once a moderator sees the flag and removes those comments, yes.