# Do @replies to deleted comments work, too?

Tags: support, fun, comment-replies, deleted-comments

Say user A posts a comment, B replies harsh to it. A deletes the comment and C decides from B's reply that A deserves better and replies @A. Will A be notified?

If this is an open question: I need two volunteers, one (A) to post a comment to which I (B) will reply which (s)he then will delete. The second volunteer (C) will then deduce from my @reply A's username and also reply. A has to check back later to state whether (s)he was notified.

Comment: [placeholder for a harsh reply @RalphRickenbach] :p

Comment: So I should reply to @RalphRickenbach

Comment: @Ralph btw, let's test whether B's reply is treated differently - did you receive 0,1 or 2 notifications?

Comment: @Tobias and @Barry (fyi) - so far, 15 min after Tobias added his comment to me, I only got the notification of the first place [placeholder] comment. I wonder whether I get some notifications after my name is in the commenters list again now. I will let you know.

Comment: @Ralph - so you should get a notification from this comment.  Which I would say is correct.  If you delete a comment you are saying "exclude from any notifications" until you comment again.

Comment: @Barry - sure did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the experiment would show:

If a comment, whose commentator was referenced by @commentator in  later comment, had deleted all of his comments before the new comment directed at him was issued, he will not be notified.

If the original commentator will issue another comment later, previously added comments directed at him will not cause a notification. All comments issued after this will, as expected, result in a notification again.

This is easy to explain, it seems:

the @commentator structure does only search commentators and OP of the post (question or answer respectively, whatever has been commented). Comments that get deleted are deleted indeed and therefore the commentator does not leave a trace and can't be found.

Comment: I guess it's because deleted comments disappear [so much into the void that only Jeff can read them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/do-10k-users-get-to-read-deleted-comments).