# Do users receive notifications for replies if the target comment is deleted?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies

Assuming the following, not entirely hypothetical exchange of comments:

> **User A**: user B is a moron
>
> **Moderator C:** @userA insulting other users is not acceptable, ...

Moderator C also deleted the comment from user A, as it was clearly offensive.

Does User A get a notification for the reply of moderator C if the target comment is removed? Does it matter if the moderator removes the comment before or after writing their own comment reply?

Comment: According to [this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64823/do-replies-to-deleted-comments-work-too) no, user A won't get notified. (the code might have changed in those years since then so prefer not to close as dupe just yet)

Comment: [another one, more recent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133254/can-authors-of-deleted-comments-be-notified-using-the-reply-syntax).

Answer (score 4):

No, notifications for deleted comments only persist if it is to the author of a deleted ***post.***

It used to be that, when we deleted a post, any comment notifications were also removed from the author's inbox. We changed that behavior so you can now reach the author of the original post to explain your actions.

See [I'm a moderator dealing with a user asking a question in an answer, what do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96342/im-a-moderator-dealing-with-a-user-asking-a-question-in-an-answer-what-do-i-do/96343#96343)

Comment: @MadScientist Time for the easiest way to test this - and it looks like the message does persist even if the target comment is deleted, judging by the state of your inbox. Dunno if it affects the top bar notification or not though.

Comment: @GraceNote I don't see it in my inbox, and neither did I get a red notification.

Comment: @MadScientist Interesting. I had seen it over on [your page here](http://stackexchange.com/users/141090/mad-scientist?tab=inbox) but now it is vanished. Seems that indeed it does not persist for much at all, then.

Answer (score -3):

No, you do not get notifications however if someone deletes a post and you gained some rep points in that post, your rep points get deducted. It happened to me once

Comment: First part already answered. Second part is irrelevant.