# Why were all the comments removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-question, deleted-comments

Why were all the comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942551/how-can-i-compare-two-sets-of-1000-numbers-against-each-other) removed and is there any way to restore them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recall there was a flame war in the comments. Apparently a diamond mod deleted them.

Note that 10Ks and diamond mods [cannot read (or restore) deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/do-10k-users-get-to-read-deleted-comments).

Comment: Shame. There was some good comments on being tolerant of our non-native English speaking users. Certainly shouldn't have been classified as a flame war. Would *love* to know who deleted them.

Comment: True, though that topic sorta belongs here on meta...

Comment: So, no cause for mass deletion of all comments in my book.

Comment: We're a Q&A site, not a place for discussions, let alone discussions that have nothing to do with the question at hand. So while you may disagree (and brought it up at the right place), that doesn't change the policy for cleaning up 'noise' @webbiedave

Comment: So, why delete **all** the comments? Many did address the question directly. And is there a way to find out who performed the mass deletion?

Comment: @web - There is no way to see who deleted these comments. And the only person who could give you a solid answer about *why* would be the diamond mod who deleted them.

Comment: Shame that so much content can be wiped out by one person without explanation. Thanks for the answer and comments from everyone.