# Who or What is the shadow user in this question?

Tags: discussion, support

[Can you invoke an instantiated object's class constructor explicity in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313882/can-you-invoke-an-instantiated-objects-class-constructor-explicity-in-c)

Just before last answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how deleted users appear. There's nothing significant about "shadow", it must have been that account's name when the deletion occurred.

For instance, the person that asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/do-10k-users-get-to-read-deleted-comments) switched his/her name to "deleted" prior to deletion.

Comment: Yup, these days we update the name just before deleting to a "user12345" format, so that we can find the major content pieces by that user Id again, if needed.

Comment: LoL..nice idea!thks for answer!